# Escape > in Code128 Barcode, ZPL

Tags: java, barcode, zpl, zpl-ii, code128

I'm sending print commands with `ZPL II` to our Zebra printer.

I need to print a barcode for this string:

> 3CDkionk>Jc

Right now my ZPL code is this:

> ^FT19,200^BY3^BCN,70,N,N,N,N^FD3CDkionk>Jc^FS

The last 3 characters (`>JC`) won't be encoded in the barcode. I think the problem is that `>` is a special character for `Code 128 Barcodes` in ZPL, as it is used to change the Subset.

Is there a way to escape it? Since the character is in the subset, I'm expecting to be able to use it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

According to the ZPL manual, you should be able to use `>0J` to get a `>J`

[image: CODE128 Characters]

Comment: Oh that's how you read it! Is the first character (invocation code ><) a space?

Comment: No, I got a '^' from the first code '><'.  I had thought the blank meant it was  unsupported for that subset.